# Xcode Sort Arrays by size in objectKey

Tags: objective-c, arrays, xcode, sorting, nsarray

So I have an object of type 'id friendData'stored in a singleton class 'coreData' from which I produce a mutable array for object key "data" as follows:

```
NSMutableArray *friends = [_coreData.friendData objectForKey:@"data"];
```

I then establish a dictionary which takes user parameters using keys "id" and "name", as well as a NSMutable array *scores which is obtained by a HTTP post request.

```
NSMutableDictionary *directory = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[directory setObject:[friends valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
[directory setObject:[friends valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
[directory setObject:scores forKey:@"score"];
```

I am wanting to order object scores from highest to lowest for the purposes of a scoreboard, but it's my understanding that rearranging within a dictionary won't maintain the same order for the objects 'id' and 'name'. Is this infact possible, or is it better to reintroduce the *scores object to *friends under an appropriate key, and apply a sort algorith? If so, how? Any help, including example code and possible sort procedure would be great!

Answer (score -1):

Just sort scores array before setting it into the dictionary. I am not sure what are exactly the kind of objects you have in scores, Im guessing they are plain NStrings. In that case this should work:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [scores sortedArrayUsingComparator:^NSComparisonResult(id a, id b) {
    NSInteger first = [(NSString *)a intValue];
    NSDate *second = [(NSString *)b intValue];
    return [first compare:second];
}];

NSMutableDictionary *directory = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[directory setObject:[friends valueForKey:@"id"] forKey:@"id"];
[directory setObject:[friends valueForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
[directory setObject:sortedScoresArray  forKey:@"score"];
```

Comment: Would I not then have the problem that the index value for scores would not match the corresponding values in id and name? I would then have to perform the same rearrangement to the other two arrays with some kind of reference? And yes, they are strings. Thanks